# What is causing these horizontal lines moving vertically up the whiter portions of the video?

Tags: video-quality, camera

The camera model is a Sony, remote control model, I don't have the exact model# with me but can get it if needed.

I'm not sure when it started, but it's very noticeable now, the lines scrolling up the flag in this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw1rEMBACTmYU2huY21IU3dFWFE/view?usp=drivesdk

Can anyone tell me what is causing this,  is the camera going bad, or do the settings just require adjistment?

*Update*

Model: Sony BRC-Z330 (Purchased in 2010)

Settings:

Exposure Mode: Full Auto

Iris Limit: F11

AE Speed: MID

AGC Limit: 18dB

Ex Comp: Off

White Balance: Indoor

Comment: The camera model would be helpful, or at least the type of camera and what format you are using. What have you tried to correct the problem? Does it happen on any white object? Is the iris set to auto? What happens if you set it to manual and close iris down?

Comment: Is this also present in the source video being shown on the LCD screen ? If so, make sure it's the camera - try viewing the video on a different display. It's normal to sometimes get artifacts like this when filming computer / TV screens - it's due to the way the screens refresh.

Comment: I'll get that info soon @MichaelLiebman. Yes it's present in the source, the lines are being shown on every display.

Comment: @MichaelLibeman I only operate the cameras, I didn't set them up, so I haven't tried anything other than changing some settings, but my technical skills (and I _do_ have technical skills) are in a different area, so I don't know where to start. I can make any changes suggested, but I'm not familiar enough with cameras to make any educated guesses.

Comment: @MichaelLibeman added model and settings information, and yeah it happens on any white object.

Comment: @BigHomie, can you tell us more about how things are set up? Which output of the camera are you using?  What equipment is between the camera and the monitor? Any other cameras? Do they also have the problem? Does the camera have external reference (EXT SYNC)?

Comment: @MichaelLibeman they're using the rgb outputs, not the SDI. There is a video splitter between the camera and the various monitors/LCDs, there is one other camera and it does not have this issue. I don't think it uses an external sync, but I don't know for sure.,

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have a flickering light source that is out of sync with the camera's rolling shutter.

#### Traditional lights

You should first verify that you are filming in 60/30/24 fps in regions whose power grid uses a 60 Hz frequency, or in 25/50 fps for 50 Hz.
If that is impossible to achieve, you can also adapt your *shutter speed or angle* to be [a multiple of the utility frequency](http://urbanvideo.ca/avoid-video-flicker). Red provides a nice [calculator](http://www.red.com/tools/flicker-free-video) for this.

#### LED lights

Flickering can be particularly bad if you use low quality LEDs because their flicker index (or depth of modulation) can be [worse than conventional light sources](http://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2012/jul/characterizing-and-minimizing-led-flicker-in-lighting-applications).

They might also [flicker independently of the utility frequency](http://www.davidsatz.com/aboutflicker_en.html). This is especially true for RGB lights or when dimming.

If you can, choose good quality high frequency switching or flicker free LED drivers, or ones that are made for video. You shouldn't have any flicker problems with good LEDs. You can also try to disable dimming or setting the highest power output to reduce flicker.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. We've had the same lights in the sanctuary, would these count as flickering lights? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw1rEMBACTmYZGFWVkFMczhrS0U/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Those bulbs could be LEDs or halogens or even plain old incandescents.

Comment: @BigHomie pay particular attention to what Duvrai said wrt changing the shutter speed/angle. Just try a bunch of different variants to see what works. Naturally this means you won't get the 180degree shutter but without making any changes to lighting it should help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue come up using my Speedlight in low light situations. I found the lines disappeared below 800 ISO. I've been using this camera for years but this is a new issue and still unclear whats causing it